# sed replace only first and last space in lines

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have a file like this (with much more lines):

```
01200 Carbon metabolism (1)

01210 2-Oxocarboxylic acid metabolism (1)

01212 Fatty acid metabolism (2)

01230 Biosynthesis of amino acids (1)

00020 Citrate cycle (TCA cycle) (1)
```

and I want to replace the first and the last space for a tab, like this:

```
01230\tBiosynthesis of amino acids\t(1)

00020\tCitrate cycle (TCA cycle)\t(1)
```

I tried the following:

```
sed 's/ /\t/;s/ (/\t(/' eg_kaas_pwmap > res.tsv
```

It worked, but in lines as in the line with "`(TCA cycle)`", I got the `\t` before it, like:

```
00020\tCitrate cycle\t(TCA cycle) (1).
```

I tried some modifications, but none of it worked.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace the first and last spaces with tabs:

```
sed -E 's/^([^ ]*) /\1\t/; s/ ([^ ]*)$/\t\1/' pwmap
```

For example:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^ ]*) /\1\t/; s/ ([^ ]*)$/\t\1/' pwmap
01200   Carbon metabolism       (1)
01210   2-Oxocarboxylic acid metabolism (1)
01212   Fatty acid metabolism   (2)
01230   Biosynthesis of amino acids     (1)
00020   Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)       (1)
```

#### How it works

- `s/^([^ ]*) /\1\t/`

  The regex `^([^ ]*)` matches all nonblanks from the beginning of the line up to the first blank and puts them in group 1. This is replaced with group 1 followed by a tab.
- `s/ ([^ ]*)$/\t\1/`

  The regex `([^ ]*)$` matches from the last blank to up to the end of the line with all the non-blanks stored in group 1.  This is replace with a tab followed by group 1.